# Prototypal inheritance and Object.create

Tags: javascript

I thought I understood exactly what I was doing when it came to JavaScript prototypal inheritance.  Turns out it's a cruel mistress.  Here's an example that I came up with using Pokemon (Yes, Pokemon...) to demonstrate how different evolutions could inherit from one another.

```
function Squirtle(firstPower) {
    this.firstPower = firstPower;
}
Squirtle.prototype.useFirstPower = function () {
    console.log("Using " + this.firstPower);
}
function Wartortle(firstPower, secondPower) {
    Squirtle.call(this, firstPower);
    this.secondPower = secondPower;
}
Wartortle.prototype.useSecondPower = function () {
    console.log("Using " + this.secondPower);
}
var mySquirtle = new Squirtle("water squirt");
mySquirtle.useFirstPower(); //works

//squirtle evolved
mySquirtle.prototype = Object.create(Wartortle.prototype);
mySquirtle.useSecondPower(); //no method found
```

The desired effect here is to keep the `prototype` methods of `Wartortle.prototype` and the methods of `Sqruitle.prototype`.  I assumed by using `Squirtle.call(...)` in the `Wartortle` constructor would allow me to inherit all of the methods.  Apparently not.  I feel like I am most lost than ever with this stuff.

How do I inherit properly and keep all of the methods from super and sub constructors??  What I am doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

As mentioned below, I can create a new object using `new Wartortle` but I think what I am after is augmenting the original object all together.  How would that work or doesn't it?

Comment: so should `mySquirtle` inherit from `Wartortle` or the other way around? Because you kind of mixed it up. You are also setting the `prototype` property of an object, which is useless, since only functions have that property.

Comment: @basilikum `Wartortle` would be the evolved version of `Squirtle` ... So, `Wartortle` should have the same methods that `Squirtle` does.

Comment: But you are trying to access `useSecondPower` within a Squirtle Object, which is a method of Wartortle? Or is the idea to transform a created object from Squirtle to Wartortle?

Comment: @basilikum The idea would be to transform the object from `Squirtle` to `Wartortle` and have all method available to the new object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how "normal" inhertitance work:

```
function Squirtle(firstPower) {
    this.firstPower = firstPower;
}
Squirtle.prototype.useFirstPower = function () {
    console.log("Using " + this.firstPower);
}
function Wartortle(firstPower, secondPower) {
    Squirtle.call(this, firstPower);
    this.secondPower = secondPower;
}

//Wartortle inherits from Squirtle
Wartortle.prototype = Object.create(Squirtle.prototype);
//Wartortle methods
Wartortle.prototype.useSecondPower = function () {
    console.log("Using " + this.secondPower);
}
var mySquirtle = new Squirtle("water squirt");
var myWartortle = new Wartortle("water squirt plus", "ice blast");
```

Now you can create squirtle and wartortle object separately, with every wartortle instance inherits the methods of squirtle.

Now, if you have a squirtle object and want to transform it into an wartortle object, you basically have two options:

1) write a transform function:

```
function transform(squirtle, secondPower) {
    return new Wartortle(squirtle.firstPower, secondPower);
}
```

2) or you manipulate the `__proto__` property, which is as far as I know the only way to truly change an object to be an instance of another constructor:

```
squirtle.__proto__ = Wartortle.prototype;
squirtle.secondPower = "awsome secone power";
```

I would stick to the first method though, since `__proto__` istn't supported everywhere.

Comment: Change the `mySquirtle.prototype` to just `Squirtle.prototype` and you have a working example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your squirtle to be a wartortle, the shouldn't you create a new object?

```
mySquirtle = new Wartortle("water squirt", "water gun");
mySquirtle.useSecondPower();
=> Using water squirt
=> Using water gun
```

*Edit*

To transform the squirtle, you can assign it a new prototype to the object itself and set the second power:

```
mySquirtle.__proto__ = Wartortle.prototype;
mySquirtle.secondPower = "water gun";
```

*Edt 2*

The issue with changing the object is that the prototype is for the function, and not for the object created with `new`. So if you were to change the prototype of `Squirtle` you would be giving all squirtles the new powers.

Objects have a reference to their prototype, but do not have a prototype themselves:

```
console.log(mySquirtle.prototype);
=> undefined
```

So you could add the methods to the object directly, but then you would have lots of repeated functions defined on objects instead of defined on one prototype.

Comment: I tried this and while this works, I am curious as to transforming the original object in question.

Comment: Keep in mind, `__proto__` is a Firefox specific implementation, so this won't work everywhere.

Comment: Fails in Chrome and I am sure Safari.

Comment: `__proto__` is supported in chrome as far as I know. But you really shouldn't use it.

Comment: I just ran this example in Chrome and it failed.

Comment: Still +1 for explaining the object references bit of this.